# Visual Studio build - Issue with comma in path

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, build

I have some external project libraries that I'm pulling into my ASP.NET app. All projects are stored in TFS and locally stored in a relative directory like so: "C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive - Company Name, LLC\Projects\Workspaces\..\..". I've been using this same structure for the past YEAR. However all of the sudden I am having an issue compiling this project where VS is doing something odd with one of the external projects path. I'll see these different errors like so:

1. 'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive - Company Name', or one of its
   dependencies, was not found.
2. 'LLC\Projects\Workspaces\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\Project1.dll',
   or one of its dependencies, was not found.

As you can see, for whatever reason Visual Studio is splitting the path on the comma, which is messing all of this up. I have found this [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1068332/Build-error-could-not-find-library) post that explains the EXACT issue I am having, however his "solution" is not a workable solution in a TFS environment.

The main issue I am confused about is that these errors didn't start to appear until this past week. I had just pulled our most recent source from TFS, and then it broke. Obviously this points to some sort of difference in the way this lib was referenced, however nothing had changed. It was referenced via:

```
<Reference Include="Project1">
    <HintPath>..\..\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\Project1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I also tried adding it as a project reference instead, as it SHOULD be:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Project1\Project1\Project1.csproj">
    <Project>{50063d52-d6f3-46dd-b001-778222ef5864}</Project>
    <Name>ArcadiumLeadCommon</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Other things to note. Been using VS 2019 for about a month now, previously using VS 2017. Tried VS 2017, but it fails as well. Build also seems to fail in the same way via cmd prompt with msbuild and devenv.

One solution would be to find a way to rename my one drive folder name to exclude the comma, however even if I find a way to do that, it could break MORE things. Ideally I'd just like to get it to work like it did before. The folder structure is the exact same as before, so there should be a way.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

---

**UPDATE:**
Figured out a quick and dirty "hack" that wont break other shortcuts and pinned document links. Use the 'mklink' cmd to create a junction point between onedrive and some other folder location. For example:

```
mklink /J "C:\OneDrive\" "C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive - Company Name, LLC\"
```

Afterwards the project built successfully. Still would prefer it to work like it did, however this is an acceptable workaround for the time being. Hope this helps someone else too.

Comment: All links in project files are relative, that means if you want to rename your `OneDrive - Company Name, LLC` folder to remove the comma it shouldn't break any project references. Of course VS won't be able to find your sln files in the "recent files" listing, but that's fine.

Comment: Or, just don't put your code in the OneDrive folder. It creates a long folder path (which, yes, long folder paths are _still_ a thing), and OneDrive will lock files as it uploads them which can cause VS to fail to compile for a short time.

Comment: It's more than just that. Pretty much every document I work with is stored in that Drive. So ALL of my pinned docs and shortcuts will break. It will be a pain in the rear, but I can work with it. The problem is that I haven't found a proper way to do this for a OneDrive for Work folder. Only suggestions seems to be to rename the name in the 365 admin portal itself, which is not an option. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yup, I understand that risk and it's been more-or-less, manageable, however again it's worked previously. Other projects in a relative directory do not have this problem (yet).